# HttpsCookieFilter - IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Tags: java, servlets, spring-security, servlet-filters

Following exception is thrown every once in a while and it shows up in localhost log file in tomcat log directory. If anyone know how to get rid of it, all help would be appreciated. BTW the filter is working fine I just don't know why this exception is happening.

#### Stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:611)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:198)
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:112)
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:112)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.processTemplate(FreeMarkerView.java:366)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.doRender(FreeMarkerView.java:283)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.renderMergedTemplateModel(FreeMarkerView.java:233)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractTemplateView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractTemplateView.java:167)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:65)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:381)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:57)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)  

 //Here is the servlet I suspect is trowing the exception. 
 at package.HttpsCookieFilter.doFilter(HttpsCookieFilter.java:38)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:886)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:721)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:2256)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:717)
```

#### The HttpsCookieFilter class:

```
public class HttpsCookieFilter implements Filter {
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(HttpsCookieFilter.class);

@Override
public void destroy() {
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    final HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    final HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    final HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);

    if (session != null) {
       setCookie(req, res);
    }
    try{  

        chain.doFilter(request, response); // <- Exception thrown from here  

    }catch (IllegalStateException e){
        log.warn("HttpsCookieFilter redirect problem! ", e);
    }
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
}

 private void setCookie( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", request.getSession(false).getId());
    cookie.setMaxAge(-1);
    cookie.setPath(getCookiePath(request));
    cookie.setSecure(false);
    response.addCookie(cookie);
}

private String getCookiePath(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
    return contextPath.length() > 0 ? contextPath : "/";
}
}
```

#### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>httpsCookieFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.iteezy.server.web.servlet.HttpsCookieFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpsCookieFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>filterChainProxy</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>filterChainProxy</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
...
```

#### The reason for integrating this filter comes from Spring security FAQs:

[I'm using Tomcat (or some other servlet container) and have enabled HTTPS for my login page, switching back to HTTP afterwards. It doesn't work - I just end up back at the login page after authenticating.](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#faq-tomcat-https-session)
This happens because sessions created under HTTPS, for which the session cookie is marked as “secure”, cannot subsequently be used under HTTP. The browser will not send the cookie back to the server and any session state will be lost (including the security context information). Starting a session in HTTP first should work as the session cookie won't be marked as secure.

#### Solution:

As it turned out the culprit was:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/captcha.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelMap processCaptcha(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
```

Simple change of the return type of the method from ModalMap to void fixed the problem.
Thank you @BalusC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The filter has nothing to do with it. It's just the point where the uncaught exception is been caught.

As the exception hints, you cannot call both [`getOutputStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream%28%29) and [`getWriter()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter%28%29) on the same response. That's an illegal state.

As the stacktrace hints, you seem to be using Freemarker which is implicitly using the `Writer` to write the response body. Whenever you delegate the response to Freemarker, you should thus ensure that you never call `response.getOutputStream()` anywhere in the code beforehand. Or, when calling it is mandatory (e.g. to write some binary content which is then to be provided as a download), then you should skip delegating the response to Freemarker.

Comment: So you're manually calling `getOutputStream()` on the response? Why? And yes, you should not be doing this whenever you delegate the response to a view technology which uses `getWriter()`.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to call the outputstream of the response while handling uploaded files. The other cases makes sense, you should in those cases be skipping/disabling delegating the resposne to Freemarker.

Comment: What's the functional requirement behind writing the uploaded file back to the response? It makes certainly no sense. Or is it actually a file downloader? If so, then it makes sense. The JCaptcha servlet looks fine, as long as it doesn't delegate the response to freemarker. You also seem so be uncertain about on which requests this exception occurs (otherwise it would have been more obvious), you might want to log the `request.getRequestURI()`.