# "getOutputStream() has already been called for this response" when tried to download generated file

Tags: jsf, primefaces, apache-poi

Ok,

I build a simple application using Spring, MyFaces, Primefaces and Omnifaces. There is a feature that generate a Excel file using Apache POI and send this generated file to client. But, on Managed Bean, when I try to send the file, I am getting a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response`.

On my Managed Bean, I have this method to generate and send file to client:

```
public void exportarPlanilhaRateio() {
    try {
        Workbook wb = getFaturaTitularService().exportarRateioPlanilha(this.fatura);
        HttpServletResponse response = Faces.getResponse();
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + this.fatura.getAnoMesReferencia() +"rateio.xls");
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        wb.write(out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (ServiceException e) {
        logger.error("Erro ao criar planilha de rateio", e);
        this.addMessage(MENSAGEM_GLOBAL, "Erro", "Erro ao criar planilha de rateio", FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Erro ao preparar download planilha de rateio", e);
        this.addMessage(MENSAGEM_GLOBAL, "Erro", "Erro ao preparar download da planilha de rateio", FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
    }
}
```

After ending the execution, I am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:214)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:105)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.getWriter(SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.java:109)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.getResponseOutputWriter(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:185)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.createResponseWriter(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2296)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1951)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:298)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:59)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:116)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:241)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I tried some other stuff to make this work, but without success. I tried using `Faces.sendFile()` of omnifaces. No exception and no success too. The response never come back after execution on Managed Bean. I've searched other questions here in stackoverflow, but none helped me. I checked my code to verify if`getResponse()` is called before, and found nothing.

Where am I wrong here?

Comment: There was already a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574511/httpscookiefilter-illegalstateexception-getoutputstream-has-already-been-ca) ... so getWriter() and getOutputStream() don't go well together ...

Comment: @kiwiwings, I just found the solution. This is not about getWriter() with getOutputStrem(). There is some problem with ajaxStatus of primefaces with getResponse().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution (or my mistake).

I am using a primefaces ajax status. You can see it in action here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajaxStatus.jsf. However, when I try to download something using response and ajax status, the problem occurs.

My Ajax Status:

```
<p:ajaxStatus onstart="statusDialog.show();" onsuccess="statusDialog.hide();"/>
```

I simply disabled ajax on `commandLink` using attribute `ajax="false"` and everything works fine.

So, just do not use ajax when your are trying to download something and you have a ajaxStatus in your page.